# Retrofit - Base URL is changed when request process is being executed

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, retrofit

Here is my code:

EC2API.java

```
public interface EC2API {
    @Multipart
    @POST("identify_k")
    Call<JSONObject> identification_result(@Part MultipartBody.Part image,
                                           @Part("k") RequestBody number);
}
```

EC2Client.java

```
public class EC2Client {
    EC2API service;

    RequestBody k;
    MultipartBody.Part file;

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();


    public EC2Client(HashMap<String, Integer> dictionaryValues, File data) 
        throws ProtocolException, MalformedURLException {

        service = generateRetrofit();

        RequestBody fileRequest = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), data);
        file = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("img", null, fileRequest);
        k = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), String.valueOf(dictionaryValues.get(IdentifyPlant.KEY_K)));
    }

    public void executeRequest(){

        Call<JSONObject> webserviceResponse = service.identification_result(file, k);

        webserviceResponse.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response) {
                Log.d("WEBSERVICE SUCCESSFUL!", response.raw().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("WEBSERVICE ERROR!", "Error retrieving data from webservice");
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private EC2API generateRetrofit(){
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://ec2-32-45-90-127.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();


        EC2API service = retrofit.create(EC2API.class);

        return service;
    }
}
```

When I execute the request, those are the body first lines:

`POST http://ec2-32-45-90-127.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/identify_k http/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=beb8961f-4f2b-4fbd-9e95-9063d90df90f
...`

As you can see, it is sending the request to `http://ec2-32-45-90-127.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/identify_k`

But later, after the request is sent, I receive the following message on the logs:

`HTTP FAILED: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to ec2-32-45-90-127.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/32.45.90.127:8080`

The destination address is being altered in a weird way. What could be it?

EDIT: I have tried it with Postman using the same details and the request looks similar to the one Retrofit is trying to send, but I receive a successful response. So it seems that it is a Retrofit issue.

Just in case: I have altered the original URL for this question.

Comment: possibly a redirect? Try going through a proxy server to see the real network traffic.

Comment: Excuse me, how can I do that?

Comment: `POST http://ec2-32-45-90-127.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/identify_k http/1.1` looks distinctly wrong. A proper HTTP request looks like `POST /identify_k HTTP/1.1` followed by `Host: ec2-32-45-90-127.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot completely true. The problem is that I can't find a way to set the host using Retrofit.

Comment: That is what `baseUrl` does, doesn't it?  Then `@Post("/identify_k")`?

Comment: Yes, I have set that, but the request keeps being the same as posted. No host on the headers, even putting the slash on identify_k